# Is it possible to open Internet Explorer window from Firefox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I need a link on a page, by clicking on it from Mozilla Firefox a new URL will be opened in a new Internet Explorer window.

I haven't tried anything because I haven't any ideas how it could be implemented.

Comment: My instinct tells me that this is impossible, but if I'm wrong I'll be afraid. Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Yup, can't be done. At least not reliably or without browser plugins.